# Execute an External Binary from a JavaScript Function/PHP Page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I would like to use the drag/drop feature of HTML5 to allow a user to drop a sequences of images. Recovering this list of files is not a problem. Then I'd need to process these files with an external binary (running on the local machine / please assume the all website runs on localhost for now) to convert this sequence of images to a movie file.

I have the program that converts images to a movie file. It's a command line tool.
The webpage is HTML, but the data from the drag & drop operation can either be processed by some JavaScript or PHP code.

Question(s):

- how can you call this external program (and have it run) if possible at all.
- how can I pass the arguments (the file name, the first and last frame for instance) to this program,
- is there a way to "call back" the web page when the conversion is done so as to display to the user the resulting movie file in the same or new page (*you get the idea*).

I am new to PHP/JS/Web programming (but I am a programmer). I realise this request might be something difficult to do, but I could just get a least some directions, hints, etc. it would be fantastic. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is your "external program" [FFMPEG](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) perhaps?

Comment: use ajax to talk from js to php and php to talk to the command line. it would likely be better to use node.js for the command-line stuff if you want progress feedback...

Comment: @tadman: something similar yes.

Comment: Is PHP a strict requirement?

Comment: @Tadman: not at all. This is what I am using at the moment because I also need to store information about the converted movie files, etc. to a db. but I can use other things I guess.

Comment: If you're writing a lot of client-side JavaScript to handle this, worth checking out [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) rather than having to wrestle with PHP. Then it's JavaScript <-> JavaScript. It has a [whole bunch of `ffmpeg` interfacing libraries](https://www.npmjs.org/search?q=ffmpeg).

Comment: @tadman: thx, will have a look.